# OpenSSL@1.1 not getting linked with Homebrew - trying to install postgresql

Tags: postgresql, openssl, homebrew

My system is OS Mojave 10.14.6, when I try to install postgresql I have this error:

```
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  RuntimeError: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1 not present or broken
Please reinstall openssl@1.1. Sorry :(
```

When I try to install openssl@1.1 I have this message:

```
brew install openssl@1.1
Running `brew update --preinstall`...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).
==> Updated Casks
Updated 8 casks.

Warning: openssl@1.1 1.1.1n is already installed, it's just not linked.
To link this version, run:
  brew link openssl@1.1
➜  / brew link openssl@1.1
Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: openssl@1.1
If you need to have openssl@1.1 first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"

For pkg-config to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

And then when I try to force hombrew link openssl, I get this message

```
Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: openssl@1.1
If you need to have openssl@1.1 first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"

For pkg-config to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

I added the lines to .zshrc file like suggested:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

But I kept on having the message when retrying to intall postgresql

```
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  RuntimeError: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1 not present or broken
```

I have read and try everything I found on the net regarding this question. I don't find any solution, any help would be very useful thanks!

UPDATE:
I got homebrew from this command :

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

and The pg version in my rails gemfile is
gem "pg", "1.3.5"
but I just tried brew install pg,
and bundle install fails also

UPDATE 2
when trying to

```
brew reinstall openssl
```

openssl@3 is installed and I get this message:

```
openssl@3 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS provides LibreSSL.
```

and then when I try to

```
brew install postgresql
```

I have the same error:
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
RuntimeError: /usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1 not present or broken
Please reinstall openssl@1.1.

Comment: 1) Where are you getting the Homebrew package from? 2) Postgres version?  Add as update to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same issue and did much of what cecileRx did as well to no avail. I am getting this issue as part of the 'brew install px4-sim-jmavsim' step in this PX4-Autopilot setup.
https://docs.px4.io/master/en/dev_setup/dev_env_mac.html

**UPDATE:** I think I got around this by uninstalling openssl and then installing openssl@1.1

```
brew uninstall openssl
brew install openssl@1.1
```

Running those two commands resolved the errors I was getting that matched those described in the questions.